# Magento2 Order status not getting updated

Tags: magento2, invoice

Magento2 I need to create Invoice & Shipping pro-grammatically. For that I used following link

> https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-create-invoice-in-magento2/

Using this code I am able to create invoice as per need but the order status is not getting updated as per need when more then 1 order Id's are passed in foreach loop. Only the last order Id's status is getting **completed**. Rest all order Id's invoice are getting created by status stays as **pending**

```
public function execute()
    {

        $api_response_array = [22,23];

        
        //load by order 

        // Load Order details based on order Id, if order is in pending state create invoice & then shipment else directly shipment

        $responseOrderId = '';

        foreach ($api_response_array as $value) {
            $responseOrderId = $value;
        
        
        //$responseOrderId = 5;

        $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
         ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
         ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$responseOrderId);

         $status = '';

        $logger->info(print_r($collection->getData(), true));
         foreach ($collection->getData() as $value) {
            $status = $value['status'];
         }

         if ((!empty($status)) && ($status == 'pending')) {
            // Pending > First Invoice & then Shipment

            $this->createInvoice($responseOrderId);

            $this->createShipment($responseOrderId);

         }elseif ($status == 'processing') {
            // Processing direct shipment

            $this->createShipment($responseOrderId);

         }

        }
}

    public function createShipment($orderId)
    {
            // Code start to create shipment
            $order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
            ->load($orderId);

            // Check if order can be shipped or has already shipped
            if (! $order->canShip()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __('You can\'t create an shipment.')
                            );
            }

            // Initialize the order shipment object
            $convertOrder = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
            $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

            // Loop through order items
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
                // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
                if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }

                $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

                // Create shipment item with qty
                $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

                // Add shipment item to shipment
                $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
            }

            // Register shipment
            $shipment->register();

            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

            try {
                // Save created shipment and order
                $shipment->save();
                $shipment->getOrder()->save();

                // Send email
                $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
                    ->notify($shipment);

                $shipment->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __($e->getMessage())
                            );
            }

            // Code end to create shipment
    }

    public function createInvoice($orderId)
    {
            // Code start to create invoice

            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
            if ($order->canInvoice()) {
            $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
            $invoice->register();
            $invoice->save();
            $transactionSave = $this->transaction->addObject(
                $invoice
            )->addObject(
                $invoice->getOrder()
            );
            $transactionSave->save();
            $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice);
            //Send Invoice mail to customer
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('Notified customer about invoice creation #%1.', $invoice->getId())
            )
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                ->save();
            }

            $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/delivered_order_status_updation.log');
            $logger = new \Zend_Log();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
        

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
            $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;

            $logger->info('------------ Reached ---------');

            $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
            $order->save();
            // Code end to create invoice
    }
```

Comment: share your code what you are trying?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya added

Answer (score 0):

Your code need to look like this.

```
public function execute()
{
        $api_response_array = [22,23];
       
        foreach ($api_response_array as $OrderId) 
        {
           $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
               ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
               ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
               ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$OrderId);

            $orderstatus = '';

            foreach ($collection->getData() as $Orderdata) 
            {
                  $orderstatus = $Orderdata['status'];
            }

            if ((!empty($orderstatus)) && ($orderstatus == 'pending')) 
            {
                $this->createInvoice($OrderId);
                $this->createShipment($OrderId);
            } 
            if ((!empty($orderstatus)) && ($orderstatus == 'processing') 
            {
                 $this->createShipment($OrderId);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhiren.. I will try it.